# Regular expression pattern to replace in Python

Tags: python, regex

Apologies if a similar question is answered already. But here is what I am struggling with, to get a regular expression replace for.

My input text has this sample

`" var1 || literal "`

I need a regular expression sub to something like this

`" concat var1 , literal "`

Essentially, || should be replaced with a comma and the first element should be prefixed with a "concat". I may have multiple such occurances in a given input and so I should replace everywhere.

Here is where I am stuck. I can build the regex pattern, but I am not sure how to substitute it and with that.

`re.sub(r'\s{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*\|\|\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*, '??????', input_string)`

I am not sure if this can be done in a single Python statement.

I have an alternative to run through the string in loop and get each occurance and replace it individually without using regular expression.

Thanks in advance.
Radha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the python `re` module, you can replace by regex by putting terms in parentheses in the pattern, then replacing then using `\1`, `\2` etc. in order of the terms.

```
re.sub(r'\s{1}([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*\|\|\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*', r'concat \1 , \2', input_string)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked, but its working only for the first occurance, I have multiple occurances in multiple lines. I have used the flag re.MULTILINE, though didn't help much.

Comment: Please ignore, it worked, I made a mistake in my code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You may handle this requirement using `re.sub` with a callback function:

```
sql = "select var1 || literal || var2 from yourTable"
def to_concat(matchobj):
    return "concat(" + re.sub(r'\s*\|\|', ',', matchobj) + ")"

sql_out = re.sub(r'\S+(?:\s+\|\|\s+\S+)+', lambda x: to_concat(x.group()), sql)
print(sql + "\n" + sql_out)
```

This prints:

```
select var1 || literal || var2 from yourTable
select concat(var1, literal, var2) from yourTable
```

The idea here is to first match the entire expression involving the ANSI `||` concatenation operator.  Then, we pass this to a callback function which then selectively replaces all `||` by comma, as well as forms the function call to `concat`.